# Is this a subspace? Simple example.

Tags: linear-algebra

Disclaimer: I am a lot better at visualizing maths than I am at proofs.

Let $V$ be the vector space of continuous functions on the interval $[−1,1]$ with the usual addition and scalar multiplication. Is it true that $U =\{f \in V: \int_0^{\frac 12} f(t)dt=0\}$ is a subspace of $V$?

Now I know that the above integral is zero only for odd functions, since we need half the function to be above zero and half the function to be below zero. For example $x(x-\frac 12)(x-\frac 14)$ has an integral of zero from $0$ to $\frac 12$. And any odd functions with roots of $0$,$\frac12$ and $\frac14$ also satisfy the conditions. But where to from here?

Oh and you probably already know this but the $\frac14$ came because the polynomial would have to go through zero, go down and them come up, and $\frac14$  is halfway between 0 and $\frac12$.

Comment: If $f,g\in U$ is it true that $f+g\in U$?

Comment: Well I vote yes because the sum of two odd functions is an odd function.

Comment: There are non-odd functions which lie in $U$.

Comment: $U$ need not consist solely of odd functions. Leaving aside the question of odd functions, is it true for any $f,g\in U$.

Comment: @D_S oh yes you are right.

Comment: @Shahab yes it is true.

Comment: How about $\alpha f$? Is $\alpha f$ also in $U$ for any $f\in U,\alpha\in \mathbb R$?

Comment: I see where you are going. Yes is is. So therefore U is a subspace. Then what about this example, U={f∈V: f(1)=1} on the interval [-1,1]. I know the criteria is the same but the notation confuses me.

Comment: For example, x^n are all functions where f(1)=1, but so is nx-(n-1) and many others are too. How would I test for subspaces?

Comment: Your latter function is not a subspace because there is no zero vector in $U$. The criteria will also fail to hold because $(f+g)(1)=f(1)+g(1)=1+1=2\ne 1$ in this case.

Comment: Oh yeh, thought so. Thanks so much.